# Python MySQLDB - not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql

When I execute my programme I have this error :

> ```
> query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> ```

I tried to fixe it but nothing worked. This is my code.
Thanks for your help.

```
con = mdb.connect('localhostt', '****', '*********', 'credentials');

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Data")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Data(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
                 Name VARCHAR(25))")

    name1 = "Paste"
    country_code = 'PSE'
    district = 'Someyork'
    population = 10008

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Data(Name) VALUES(%s) ",(name1))
    con.comit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Data(Name) VALUES(%s)", (name1,))
```

Notice the extra comma in `(name1,)` - it's needed to make it a tuple. Without the comma, it's the same as

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Data(Name) VALUES(%s)", name1)
```

and since strings are sequences too, the connector iterates over each char in `name1`, hence the error.